# DateComponents giving wrong date

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to convert today's date using DateComponents:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current        
//add today's date
var todayDate = Date()
var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: todayDate)
dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone.current
todayDate = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
```

While debugging I found that after declaring todayDate, its value was `2016-11-11 07:44:44 +0000`. After using dateComponents, the value changed to `2016-11-10 18:30:00 +0000`. Whereas according to my location, the day should be 11th November, and the time should be somewhere between 1 or 2 PM. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified a timezone, nor hours minutes and seconds in your components.  So, all these values are assumed to be zero.  The resulting time is at midnight GMT on the year, month and day that you specified.

When you printed the result, you specified your current timezone, which appears to be 5h 30m different.

I'm guessing you are in India.

Comment: I have specified `dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone.current` above. Let me try adding hours and minutes as well and try again

Comment: After adding .hour and .minute, the date is correct but the time is still in UTC.

Comment: You need to extract the timezone, too.  Not set it separately.